# Update livestreaming title

Tags: youtube-api

I want to not log onto YouTube to change my video title, but instead script it.
The API documents are pretty confusing and don't really show examples of how to use everything so hopefully I am close.

The code executes, but when I look at the video the title has not been updated.

```
function liveTitle() {
  var videoID = 'my video id'
  var part = ['snippet'];
  var params = {'id': videoID};

  var response = YouTube.Videos.list(part, params);
  var video = response.items[0];

  video.snippet.title = 'new video title here';

  try{
    YouTube.LiveBroadcasts.update(video, part);
  } 
  catch(e){}
}
```

Comment: You should look for the error response of your `update` call. A [video `snippet` object](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#snippet) is very much different than a [live broadcast `snippet` object](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveBroadcasts#snippet). Also you [need to be properly authorized](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveBroadcasts/update#auth) to apply such an update operation.

Comment: I am authorized and not getting any errors.  If I try getting data (like concurrentViewers) it works because it is reading from YouTube.Videos.  The issue is the YouTube.LiveBroadcasts.update

Comment: I do believe that you're in fact getting errors, but your empty `catch` hides them away from you.

Comment: Oh right.  I took it out of the catch statement and am now getting the following error:
`GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to youtube.liveBroadcasts.update failed with error: The user is not enabled for live streaming.`
I am trying to update a branded YouTube account livestream, but the account I am writing the script from is the email from the branded account which does not have a YouTube channel.  Do I need to create a personal YouTube account along with the branded one?